# Java - Reading from txt file and storing in array

Tags: java, input, io, load, output

I am working on a small library application which is able to save manuals stored to a text file, and load said text file back. However currently I am unable to store the library in an array, as once the user loads a file they are simply displayed the text within the console area.

How can I get the loaded library.txt file to be stored in the library rather than printed to the console?

Here is my manual class with the save implementation:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Manual {

String serial;
String title;
String author;
String publicationYear;
String status;
String borrower;
String borrowDate;
String returnDate;  

Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 

/**
 * Display the Manual:
 * @return ManualInfo
 */
final String displayManual(){

    String ManualInfo ="\nSerial Number: ........... "+serial+ 
                    "\nTitle: ................... "+title+
                    "\nAuthor: .................. "+author+
                    "\nPublication Year: ........ "+publicationYear+
                    "\nStatus: .................. "+status+
                    "\nBorrower: ................ "+borrower+
                    "\nDate Borrowed: ........... "+borrowDate+
                    "\nReturn date: ............. "+returnDate+
                    "\n";
    return ManualInfo;  
}   

/**
 * Creates the Manual.
 */
final void createManual(){

    serial = Console.readString(Messages.enterSerialMessage, Messages.tooShortMessage, 3);
    title = Console.readString(Messages.enterTitleMessage, Messages.tooShortMessage, 2);
    author = Console.readString(Messages.enterAuthorMessage, Messages.tooShortMessage, 3);
    publicationYear = Console.readString(Messages.enterPublicationYearMessage, Messages.tooShortMessage, 4);

    borrower = "N/A";
    borrowDate = "N/A";
    returnDate = "N/A";

    status = "Available";
}   

/***
 * Runs the main part of the program and terminates if the choice is 0.
 */
public void run(){

    User.addUser();
    Menu.displayMenu();//Displays the main menu and ask for choice.

    exit:           
        while(Menu.menuChoice != 0){


            if(Menu.menuChoice == 1 && Library.ManualList.size() > 0){                      
                Library.displayManualList();
                boolean saveYesNo = Console.readYesNo("The ManualKeeper® app is able to save your current library to a '.txt' \nfile in your workspace directory.\n\nWould you like to save the current library? (Y/N):\n");
                if(saveYesNo){
                    try {
                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Library.txt");
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

                        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < Library.ManualList.size(); i1++){
                            pw.println("-------------------- Index Number: " + i1 + " --------------------");
                            pw.println(Library.ManualList.get(i1).displayManual());
                            pw.println("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
                        }
                        pw.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error! Library unable to save.");
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("\n                              Library saved!\n");
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                }
                    else if(saveYesNo){
                        System.out.println("\n");
                }   
                Menu.displayMenu();
            }

            if(Menu.menuChoice == 1 && Library.ManualList.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(Messages.addManualFirst);
                Menu.displayMenu();
            }
            if(Menu.menuChoice == 1 && Library.ManualList.size() > 0){                      
                Library.displayManualList();
                boolean saveYesNo = Console.readYesNo("The ManualKeeper® app is able to save your current library to a '.txt' \nfile in your workspace directory.\n\nWould you like to save the current library? (Y/N):\n");
                if(saveYesNo){
                    try {
                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Library.txt");
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

                        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < Library.ManualList.size(); i1++){
                            pw.println("-------------------- Index Number: " + i1 + " --------------------");
                            pw.println(Library.ManualList.get(i1).displayManual());
                            pw.println("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
                        }
                        pw.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error! Library unable to save.");
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("\n                              Library saved!\n");
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                }
                    else if(saveYesNo){
                        System.out.println("\n");
                }   
                Menu.displayMenu();
            }

            if(Menu.menuChoice == 1 && Library.ManualList.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(Messages.addManualFirst);
                Menu.displayMenu();
            }
```

Here is my startLibrary class with my load implementation:

```
public class startLibrary {

/**
 * The main method.
 *
 * @param args the arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("\n                 Welcome to the ManualKeeper® library app!");
    System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    boolean loadYesNo = Console.readYesNo("The ManualKeeper® app is able to load any 'Library.txt' files found in \nyour workspace directory.\n\nWould you like to load a library? (Y/N):\n");
    if(loadYesNo){
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Library.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str + "\n");
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error! File not found");
    }
    }

    Manual newManual = new Manual();
    newManual.run();




}//End of Main Method.
```

Here is my library class in full incase needed:

```
package library;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/** The Manual choice. */
public static int ManualChoice;

static String returnManualTitle;

/** The status1. */
static String status1 = "Available";

/** The status2. */
static String status2 = "Borrowed"; 

/** The Manual list. */
static ArrayList<Manual> ManualList = new ArrayList<Manual>();
static ArrayList<Manual> borrowedManuals = new ArrayList<Manual>();


/**
 * Adds the Manual.
 */
static void addManual(){
    Manual newManual = new Manual(); //create new Manual object with status "Available."
    newManual.createManual();
    ManualList.add(newManual);//add the Manual to the ManualList ArrayList.
    System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("\n                          Manual added to library!\n");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}

/**
 * Display Manual list.
 */
static void displayManualList(){
    if (ManualList.isEmpty()){//If the library is empty, it goes back to main menu and choice.
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(Messages.empltyLibraryMessage + Messages.tryAgainMessage);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
        Menu.menuChoice = 7;

    } else {    
        System.out.printf("\n\nHere are the Manual/s currently stored in the library:\n\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < ManualList.size(); i++){
            System.out.printf("-------------------- Index Number: %s --------------------\n",i);
            System.out.println(ManualList.get(i).displayManual());  
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }
        }//End of For Loop.         
    }// End of Else Statement.          

static void displayBorrowedManuals(){
    if (ManualList.isEmpty()){//If the library is empty, it goes back to main menu and choice.
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(Messages.empltyLibraryMessage + Messages.tryAgainMessage);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
        Menu.menuChoice = 7;

    } else {                    
        for (int i = 0; i < borrowedManuals.size(); i++){
            System.out.printf("-------------------- Index Number: %s --------------------\n",i);
            System.out.println(borrowedManuals.get(i).displayManual()); 
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
        }//End of For Loop.         
    }// End of Else Statement.          
}//End of if Statement.
/**
 * Borrow Manual.
 */
public static void borrowManual(){

    //register user's Manual choice.
    displayManualList();
    ManualChoice = (Console.readInteger(Messages.enterManualIndexMessage, Messages.ManualIndexNotInListMessage, 0, Library.ManualList.size() - 1));

    borrowLoop:
    while(Menu.menuChoice == 3){
        //Check if the Manual to be borrowed is available.
        //ManualChoice = (Console.readInteger(Messages.enterManualIndexMessage, Messages.ManualIndexNotInListMessage, 1, Library.ManualList.size()));

        if ((ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status.equalsIgnoreCase(status1)) && (ManualList.size() >= ManualChoice)){
            //Print the borrowed Manual information and change the Manual status to borrowed.
            ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status = "Borrowed";
            ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrower = User.userName;
            ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrowDate = "Today.";
            ManualList.get(ManualChoice).returnDate = "In two weeks.";
            //Add the borrowed Manual to the borrowedManuals arraylist:
            borrowedManuals.add(ManualList.get(ManualChoice));
            System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("\n                             Manual borrowed!\n");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            break borrowLoop;

        }else if(ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status.equalsIgnoreCase(status2) && ManualList.size() >= ManualChoice){
            System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("\n            "
                    + " The Manual you wish to borrow is already on loan.");
            System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            break borrowLoop;

        }else if(ManualChoice > ManualList.size()-1){
            System.out.println(Messages.noSuchManualMessage);
            break borrowLoop;
        }
    if(ManualList.size() > 1){
        displayManualList();
    }
    else if(ManualList.size() == 1){
        ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status = "Borrowed";
        ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrower = User.userName;
        ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrowDate = "Today.";
        ManualList.get(ManualChoice).returnDate = "In two weeks.";
        borrowedManuals.add(ManualList.get(ManualChoice));
        System.out.printf("\n\nOSCAR YOU SHOULD NOT BE SEEING THIS!!!!!!!\n\n %s\n\n", ManualList.get(ManualChoice).displayManual());
        System.out.println("Please return the Manual within two weeks!\n");
        displayManualList();
        }
    }
    Menu.displayMenu();
}

/**
 * Return Manual.
 */
static void returnManual(){
    System.out.printf("\n\nHere are the Manual/s currently out on loan:\n\n");

    if(borrowedManuals.size() > 0){
    for (int i = 0; i < borrowedManuals.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(borrowedManuals.get(i).displayManual());
        returnManualTitle = Console.readString(Messages.enterManualSerial, Messages.tooShortMessage, 3);
    }

    int x = 0;
    boolean serialExistance = false;
    while (x < ManualList.size()){//Search for the Manual by title, if it exists change it's status,
                                //it's borrower and borrowDate.

        if (ManualList.get(x).serial.equalsIgnoreCase(returnManualTitle)){

            ManualList.get(x).status = "Available";
            ManualList.get(x).borrower = "N/A";
            ManualList.get(x).borrowDate = "N/A";
            ManualList.get(x).returnDate = "N/A";

            int p = 0;
                while (p < borrowedManuals.size()) {
                    Manual borrowed = borrowedManuals.get(p); // guessing the name of this class
                    if (borrowed.serial.equalsIgnoreCase(returnManualTitle)) {
                        borrowedManuals.remove(p);
                        break;
                    }
                    p++;
                }               
            System.out.println(Messages.successReturnMessage);
            serialExistance = true;

            break;//if a title is found, break out of the loop and display choice menu.
        }
        x = x+1;
    }//end of while loop.
    if(serialExistance == false){
        boolean repeatReturnManual = Console.readYesNo("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\n\nThe Manual with the title "+"\""+returnManualTitle +"\""+ " wasn't found!"
                                                        +"\n\nDo you want to try again? (Y/N):\n");
        System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        if(repeatReturnManual){
            returnManual();
        }
    }else if(serialExistance){
        Menu.menuChoice = 7;
    }               
}

/**
 * Removes the Manual.
 */
public static void removeManual(){

    if(ManualList.size() >0){
        displayManualList();
        ManualChoice = Console.readInteger(Messages.enterRemoveManualIndex ,Messages.ManualIndexNotInListMessage, 0, ManualList.size());        
        int p = 0;
        while (p < borrowedManuals.size()){//Search for the Manual by title, if it exists change it's status,
            //it's borrower and borrowDate.

            if (borrowedManuals.get(p).title.equalsIgnoreCase(returnManualTitle)){

                borrowedManuals.remove(p);
            }
        }
        ManualList.remove(ManualChoice);
        System.out.print(Messages.successRemovedManualMessages);
        Menu.menuChoice = 7;
    }               
}

/**
 * Empty library.
 */
static void emptyLibrary(){
    System.out.println("\n                                 WARNING!");
    System.out.println("\n           You have chosen to delete all Manuals in the library.\n"); 
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    boolean emptyLibraryChoice = Console.readYesNo("\nAre you sure you wish to destroy the library? (Y/N): \n");
    System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    if(emptyLibraryChoice){
        Library.ManualList.clear();
        System.out.println(Messages.successEmptyLibraryMesssage);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        Menu.menuChoice = 7;
        }

}
```

}

Comment: I've added an answer to get you an idea. The other solution would be a database to store the manuals.

Comment: If my answer was usefule please accept and upvote it. I just wanted to give you an idea of parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you reposted the question. And I think the question was answered pretty good.
I try to explain it to you:

You save your library as a text file. You add all manuals like this:

```
"-------------------- Index Number: " + i1 + " --------------------"
                    "\nSerial Number: ........... "+serial+ 
                    "\nTitle: ................... "+title+
                    "\nAuthor: .................. "+author+
                    "\nPublication Year: ........ "+publicationYear+
                    "\nStatus: .................. "+status+
                    "\nBorrower: ................ "+borrower+
                    "\nDate Borrowed: ........... "+borrowDate+
                    "\nReturn date: ............. "+returnDate+
                    "\n";
"---------------------------------------------------------\n"
```

Now you write many of these into the library.txt file. The problem: You cant extract the information. The solution is: PARSING.
This here is just a little code you have to adapt to get it work:

```
    final String delimiterManuals = ";;;;;;;;";
    final String delimiterValues = "::::::::";

//save file
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < Library.ManualList.size() - 1; i1++)
{
    //here are all attributes
    pw.print(Library.ManualList.get(i1).title));
    pw.print(delimiterValues);
    pw.print(Library.ManualList.get(i1).author));
    pw.print(delimiterValues);
    pw.print(Library.ManualList.get(i1).publicationYear));
    pw.print(delimiterValues);
    pw.print(Library.ManualList.get(i1).status));
    pw.print(delimiterValues);
    pw.print(Library.ManualList.get(i1).borrower));
    pw.print(delimiterValues);
    pw.print(Library.ManualList.get(i1).borrowDate));
    pw.print(delimiterValues);
    pw.print(Library.ManualList.get(i1).returnDate); //this is your last attribute
    pw.print(delimiterManuals);
}
//WATCH: lastAttribute is just an example (because I don't want to write every attribute)
//last Manual has no delimiterManual at the end (end of file)
pw.print(Library.ManualList.get(Library.ManualList.size()-1).title));
pw.print(delimiterValues);
pw.print(Library.ManualList.get(Library.ManualList.size()-1).author));
pw.print(delimiterValues);
//other attributes of the manual...
pw.print(Library.ManualList.get(Library.ManualList.size()-1).lastAttribute);


ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
//load
FileReader fr = new FileReader("Library.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

String str;
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    a.add(str);
}
ArrayList<Manual> manuals = new ArrayList<Manual>()
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
{
    //split into single manuals
    String[] split1 = a.get(i).split(delimiterManuals);
    for(int j = 0; j < split1.length; ++j)
    {
        //split into single values
        String[] split2 = split1.split(delimiterValues);
        //here you have all values of a manual in the order you saved them so:
        Manual m = new Manual();
        m.title = split[0]; // <-- please don't do this! create and use setter/getter (like m.setTitle(split[0]);
        m.author = split[1]
        // till all fields are filled up
        manuals.add(m);
    }
}

//now you have all manuals in the manuals ArrayList
```

Please consider, that you really have to adapt the code. I just wanted to give you a general idea
of how to parse.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I have adapted the save part of the code however I am getting an error where the "lastAttribute" is mentioned, stating "lastAttribute cannot be resolved or is not a field". Also there is an error on the "ArrayList<String>" line, stating "Multiple markers at this line
 - ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type
 - ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
  LocalVariableDeclarationStatement" I am not sure if I have implemented that line into the right place, though :(

Comment: So I've edited my answer:
I've wrote the missing semicolon. And for lastAttribute. Of course it's not a field. This was just an example! You have to do this with all your attributes like author, title etc.
The purpose of last attribute was to show that after the last value you print delimiterManuals INSTEAD OF delimiterValues

NOTE: Writting a parser is exhausting and requires some effort. So such errors you have to look for yourself because it's specific for your parser.